# Amcharts shown, but console output one error

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, amcharts

I used Amcharts to show a chart, and I make a div for it in a Bootstrap component. Followed is my html & js code:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Chart</legend>
    <div class="row">
    <form class="form-horizontal mb-sm line-height-3">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="submitStartTime" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Start Time</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label id="submitStartTime"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="latencyChart" class="col-sm-9 col-md-9" style="height: 400px;"></div>
    </form>                         
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

js:

```
drawChart: function(graphType){
            var that = this;

            that.generateChartData();

            this.chart.dataProvider = this.chartData;
            this.chart.categoryField = "date";
            this.chart.balloon.bulletSize = 5;

            // listen for "dataUpdated" event (fired when chart is rendered) and call zoomChart method when it happens
            this.chart.addListener("dataUpdated", that.zoomChart());

            // AXES
            // category
            var categoryAxis = this.chart.categoryAxis;
            categoryAxis.parseDates = true; // as our data is date-based, we set parseDates to true
            categoryAxis.minPeriod = "DD"; // our data is daily, so we set minPeriod to DD
            categoryAxis.dashLength = 1;
            categoryAxis.minorGridEnabled = true;
            categoryAxis.twoLineMode = true;
            categoryAxis.dateFormats = [{
                period: 'fff',
                format: 'JJ:NN:SS'
            }, {
                period: 'ss',
                format: 'JJ:NN:SS'
            }, {
                period: 'mm',
                format: 'JJ:NN'
            }, {
                period: 'hh',
                format: 'JJ:NN'
            }, {
                period: 'DD',
                format: 'DD'
            }, {
                period: 'WW',
                format: 'DD'
            }, {
                period: 'MM',
                format: 'MMM'
            }, {
                period: 'YYYY',
                format: 'YYYY'
            }];

            categoryAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";

            // value
            var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
            valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
            valueAxis.dashLength = 1;
            this.chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

            // GRAPH
            var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.title = "red line";
            graph.valueField = "visits";
            graph.bullet = "round";
            graph.bulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
            graph.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
            graph.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
            graph.lineThickness = 2;
            graph.lineColor = "#5fb503";
            graph.negativeLineColor = "#efcc26";
            graph.hideBulletsCount = 50; // this makes the chart to hide bullets when there are more than 50 series in selection
            this.chart.addGraph(graph);

            // SCROLLBAR
            var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
            this.chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

            this.chart.creditsPosition = "bottom-right";

            // WRITE
            this.chart.write("latencyChart");
            this.chart.write("chartdiv");
        },

        // this method is called when chart is first inited as we listen for "dataUpdated" event
        zoomChart: function() {
            // different zoom methods can be used - zoomToIndexes, zoomToDates, zoomToCategoryValues
            this.chart.zoomToIndexes(this.chartData.length - 40, this.chartData.length - 1);
        },

        generateChartData: function(){
             var firstDate = new Date();
             firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 10);
             for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                 // we create date objects here. In your data, you can have date strings
                 // and then set format of your dates using chart.dataDateFormat property,
                 // however when possible, use date objects, as this will speed up chart rendering.
                 var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
                 newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);

                 var visits = Math.round(Math.random() * 40) - 20;

                 this.chartData.push({
                     date: newDate,
                     visits: visits
                 });
             }
        },
```

this.chart is a global variable in my js code, and it's already initialized. And the chart is shown in my page like below.[image]
But Chrome console give some error info like below.[image]
I debugged for some time and find out that the error happens in this.chart.write("latencyChart"). The error is cannot read property 'call' of undefined. Then I created a new div in this page called "chartdiv" to know whether the program can still work, and I added this.chart.write("chartdiv"); after the original one. and I found that there is no chart in "chartdiv" and the error goes on.

Comment: I don't understand do you want to create 2 charts or only one?

Comment: You can't use the same chart object for two divs if that's what you're trying to do. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: I just want to create only one chart. I added a div called "chartdiv" because I    wanted to know whether the error really happened in " this.chart.write("latencyChart");". My target is to create a chart in div called "latencyChart" and no error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is how you're assinging the `zoomChart` method to your dataUpdated event - `that.zoomChart()` is calling the zoomChart method, rather than assigning it to the event. You need to create a function that calls zoomChart so that it has access to your object's chart property during the event, i.e.

```
this.chart.addListener("dataUpdated", function() {
  that.zoomChart()
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13qrn13o/5/) with this fix.

Alternatively, you can use the [`dataUpdated` event's argument object](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#dataUpdated) to access the chart object that way instead of fiddling with this/that/etc, for example:

```
  this.chart.addListener("dataUpdated", that.zoomChart);

// ...

  zoomChart: function(e) {
    // different zoom methods can be used - zoomToIndexes, zoomToDates, zoomToCategoryValues
    e.chart.zoomToIndexes(e.chart.dataProvider.length - 40, e.chart.dataProvider.length - 1);
  },
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13qrn13o/6/)

Comment: Thank you very very much! This perfectly solves my problem! Regards!